# How to add a custom function in place of order in Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm not familiar with Prestashop but I want to execute a function in place of order with Prestashop 1.7.

My goal is when customer show his cart, he can go to checkout and go to quotation.
Quotation is just a custom function I need to get cart products and customer information and send a mail.

Is it possible to add a button in cart and execute a custom function on his click ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an action hook like

```
actionCartSummary
```

This hook called when a customer check his cart, and you can send and email or execute any function.

Or a display hook

```
displayShoppingCart
```

In this hook you can add a new button to cart page, and with that button you can redirect the customer everyere, even to a specific frontController
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/

**Update:** implement displayShoppingCart hook call frontController from that hook

Firstly, you should create a module (https://validator.prestashop.com/generator) that implements the displayShoppingCart hook.
In this module, you need to create a frontController (https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/), and then in the displayShoppingCart hook, you can generate a link to the frontController.

*Example:*

Creating a new frontController(something) in the customcheckoutfunction module:

```
<?php
/**
 * <Module> => customcheckoutfunction
 * <FileName> => something.php
 * Format expected: <ModuleClassName><FileName>ModuleFrontController
 */
class CustomcheckoutfunctionSomethingModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
     //do the stuff
}
```

displayShoppingCart hook:

```
 public function hookDisplayShoppingCart($params)
{
    $frontControllerUrl = $this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->name, 'something');
    $this->context->smarty->assign(
        array(
            'fcUrl' => $frontControllerUrl,
        )
    );
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/front/_display-shopping-cart-extra-content.tpl');
}
```

and now you can use the $fcUrl variable in the *_display-shopping-cart-extra-content.tpl* file

```
<a href="{$fcUrl}"> <button class='btn btn-primary'> Click here </button></a>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use the ActionValidateOrder hook but it's too late for me.
I think the use of displayShoopingCart with a button where I can redirect user to a controller but how I can redirect to controller with my button ?

I read your link but I don't find how I can do this.
Thank you

Comment: @Marminoleo, I have updated my answer with an example. Please check it  ;)

Comment: This work great, thank you ! I have another question about this. I use this hook to add a button but when I'm in cart page, when I update quantity, ajax refresh parts and my button is delete. There is a solution for this ?